# Aliens helping contact spirits of the dead?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, aliens

I am looking for a short story that involves a plane crash. However, aliens intervene; while they can’t save the crash victims, they have technology that lets them say goodbye to their loved ones.

Comment: Was this in an anthology? Do you remember other stories from the anthology?

Comment: It was an anthology, but I am hogtied if I know the name. If I knew the name it would be a breeze.